# How and Where Do I File A Bug Against the Ubuntu Wayland Display Manager?

Tags: suspend, wayland, 23.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10, and thought I'd try switching my display manager to Wayland, again, in case it worked better now than it did before.

Wayland worked fine at first, until I put my computer to sleep. After that the desktop background was black, and every single application was missing random content.
e.g. Click on a dropdown menu would result in half the list elements being blank.

Where can I file a bug or provide feedback, that Wayland is very unstable, and effectively unusable on my system? It broke so badly, I'm not sure I'd even be able to use ubuntu-bug to file the report while running Wayland after resume from sleep.

### Hardware Information:

- **Hardware Model:**                              Lenovo Legion Y545 PG0
- **Memory:**                                      32.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™ i7-9750H × 12
- **Graphics:**                                    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
- **Disk Capacity:**                               1.3 TB

### Software Information:

- **Firmware Version:**                            BHCN45WW
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 23.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               45.0
- **Windowing System:**                            X11
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.5.0-10-generic

**Report generated at:**                              2023-11-07 18:47:20

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: "Feedback" must be via a bug report. A proper bug report sent to the right place. A bug report that clearly shows the steps to reproduce on somebody else's hardware. Preferably a bug that can be reproduced in the "Try Ubuntu" environment of a stock 23.10 Desktop .iso. The developers are not psychic, so don't make them guess. Avoid saying things like "*Wayland is very unstable*." It's stable for them. You will need to help them (a lot!) to figure out why it's not stable for you.

Comment: I get it, I really do. I'm a software developer. What I don't get is where do I report the bug? Why is it so hard to report bugs against Wayland? 

Apparently Wayland isn't even a thing that you report bugs against, it's just a protocol. 

As an end user, the only piece of information I know is, one login option says Wayland and doesn't work, and one login option doesn't say Wayland and does work.

It's so broken, I'm not sure I could even file a bug report, even if I knew where to file it.

And yes, I've googled it, I've Duck Duck Go-ed it, I've Bing-ed it, I've ChatGPT-ed it.